# Check if a products date is overdue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a kind of check, thats check if a products date is overdue. In my product table I have a column named `veilingGesloten` (auctionClosed) that can contain the value 'yes' or 'no'.

So I made this:

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_validategesloten]
ON [dbo].[voorwerp]
after update, insert
AS
begin
    set nocount on;

    update [dbo].[voorwerp]
        set veilinGesloten =
        case when ( inserted.looptijdeindeDag <= GETDATE() ) then 'wel'
        else 'niet'
        end
    from [dbo].[voorwerp]
    inner join inserted on [dbo].[voorwerp].voorwerpnummer = inserted.voorwerpnummer;
end
```

Now im wondering how to actually make this an auto process without any insert or update events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't trigger it - you use a computed column:

```
alter table voorwerp add veilinGesloten
    as (case when looptijdeindeDag <= getdate() then 'wel' else 'niet' end);
```

Personally I would use a bit field and convert to meaningful words at the front-end.

```
alter table voorwerp add veilinGesloten
    as (convert(bit, case when looptijdeindeDag <= getdate() then 1 else 0 end));
```